cannot install centos chroot with rinse(8)
I don't know how to lather before rinse(8).
$ ubuntu-version 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

and/but
rinse   --arch amd64    \
        --distribution centos-8                 \
        --mirror http://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/                   \
        --directory /var/lib/chroot/centos-8-x86_64 
[11:172] Copy from cache: centos-gpg-keys-8-6.el8.noarch.rpm ..                                                  [Harmless] Failed to find download link for centos-release
[Harmless] Failed to find download link for centos-repos
                                                                                                                  
Extracting: chkconfig-1.19.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                    failed to extract chkconfig-1.19.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: 512 at /usr/sbin/rinse line 1261.

I am attempting to pretend Ubuntu is Debian, and to follow these instructions: Installing CentOS in a chroot under Debian. rinse(8) complains it "failed to extract" the file.  rpm -ql reports no problem.
The error appears to come from cpio(1), which returns status 2 on error.  Why is unclear: strace shows no failed syscall; all we see is that the process exits with status 2.
It's impossible afaict to test more granularly.  While the chroot directory has the rpm file, the chroot is "broken", meaning nothing works in it:
$ ls /var/lib/chroot/centos-8-x86_64/usr/bin/bash
/var/lib/chroot/centos-8-x86_64/usr/bin/bash
$ sudo chroot  /var/lib/chroot/centos-8-x86_64 /usr/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
$ sudo chroot  /var/lib/chroot/centos-8-x86_64 
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Is this supposed to work?

Try adding  Packages to the --mirror option, as in: https://mirror.vtti.vt.edu/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/.  When in doubt visit the link and browse manually.  Download the package manually, then use rpm --test on what was downloaded.

Thanks.  Adding /Packages/ made no difference.  rpm --test appears to be unsupported in the installed version, even though it's a documented option.  Every permutation of rpm --test <rpm file> just produces a "Usage" message.  :-(

What happens if you download it manually from /Packages/ and install it using rpm -i?  If it installs there is a scripting error somewhere and we work backwards.  If there's an error in the package, attempting to manually install should print the error to the terminal.  I was trying to hold off on a manual install as the package manager loses track, but we have to work backwards until we discover the cause and then fix and retry

install it ... where?  As I said, the chroot is nonfunctional at that point.  I don't know how to install an rpm into a chroot other than by activating the chroot first, and installing from within.

If the chroot is a directory on your local filesystem, you can manipulate the chroot outside of itself  If the chroot is mnt/chroot, save the file to /mnt/chroot then cd and use rpm -i

Perhaps we should back up.  rpm -i doesn't install; it produces a report.  The rpm was downloaded; as my message said, the error comes after it was downloaded, from cpio(1).  If I run rpm -i on the file, I get many messages saying libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by chkconfig-1.19.2-1.el8.x86_64 or similar, because I'm running rpm outside the chroot.  I see no reason to think the rpm itself is the problem, because (as I said) rpm -ql says the files are intact.

Is your architecture 64-bit on your 22.04 host?

yes.
$ uname -m
x86_64
